# Restructure array of Anonymous objects to named key objects in mongo in a Bulk Operation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document which looks like this

```
{
  name:'John Doe',
  phone: 'XXXXXXX',
  field1: [
    {I:20},
    {J:60},
    {K:20}
  ]
}
```

How do I get about restructuring the `field1` to have a name instead of being anonymous. something like this:

```
field1: [
  {
    key: I,
    value:20
  },
  {
    key: J,
    value:60
  },
  {
    key: K,
    value:20
  }
]
```

Also is it possible to do in a bulk op coz I have a large number of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using both way,

1. [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html) from MpngoDB 4.2
2. using [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html) and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to collection

#### using update with aggregation pipeline [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html)

- first `$set` pipeline for convert object to array in `k` and `v` format
- second `$set` pipeline for changing the name from `k => key` and `v => value`

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
  [{
      $set: {
        field1: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$field1",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  $objectToArray: "$$this"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $set: {
        field1: {
          $map: {
            input: "$field1",
            as: "f",
            in: {
              key: "$$f.k",
              value: "$$f.v"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

---

#### using `aggregate()` and `$out`

- both `$set` are same as above method
- `$out` Takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      field1: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$field1",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $objectToArray: "$$this"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      field1: {
        $map: {
          input: "$field1",
          as: "f",
          in: {
            key: "$$f.k",
            value: "$$f.v"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {  $out: <"collection name"> }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1GmuvWA_ZvR)